# How can I put plotly bar chart on the top layer

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to put a bar chart on the top of other charts using Plotly in R, but couldn't get it shown corrected. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
  library(plotly)
dat1 <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-29","2020-03-30", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-01")),
  value = c(1,3,5,7,5,3,1),
  box = c(1,2,rep(4,5))
)

fig <- plot_ly(data = dat1, x = ~ date, y = ~ box, mode = "line+markers", type='scatter', stackgroup = 'one', fillcolor='#d8f4ef' )
fig <- fig %>% add_bars(data = dat1, x= ~date, y = ~ value, inherit = F)
fig
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use **add_trace()** to  make it

[you can find example here](https://plotly.com/~anio1021/7/#code)

hope it helps

Comment: Thank-You! I changed add_bars to add_trace, but it is still not working. `fig <- plot_ly(data = dat1, x = ~ date, y = ~ box, mode = "line+markers", type='scatter', stackgroup = 'one', fillcolor='#d8f4ef' )
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data = dat1, x= ~date, y = ~ value, inherit = F, type='bar')
fig`

Comment: try **layout(barmode = 'overlay')**

Comment: It is still not working. Looks like barmode='overlay' only effects to bars, not to area charts.